# Tablerow having one listitem in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have a table row with listitem (only one item)

layout xml:

```
<TableRow android:id="@+id/first_row" >  
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.55" >
    </ListView>
</TableRow>
```

Activity class:

```
TableRow firstRow =(TableRow)findViewById(R.id.first_row);
firstRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {            
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("First row clicked", "First row clicked");                
    }
});
```

The problem is that if I click on the tablerow, then I'm not able to get the log statement.

Comment: This is probably because the 'ListView' is receiving the onClick event instead of the `TableRow`(because it's taking up the full TableRow). Aside from that, what are you trying to accomplish by adding a `ListView` to a `TableRow`?

Comment: A ListView in a TableRow? This way there trouble be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be having the click on the listview because it is handling the tablerow onclick

```
ListView list =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list1);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


    }
  });
}}
```

However, what it the purpose of having a listview inside a tablerow?

Comment: @String, try it this way then.

Answer (score 2):

Try Setting listener on "list1"as that is taking all the space of TableRow. So when you are trying to clock TableRow, You are actually clicking "list1"